# SDL/C++ camera bether ways?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

At the moment i handle the camera like that:

```
if (window.rightArrow) {
            //player.addXPosition(PLAYER_SPEED);
            if (player.getPosition().x > 400 - 50 / 2 && !cam.active)
            {
                cam.active = true;
            }
            if (cam.active && !blockedLeft)
            {
                rect.updateCameraLeft(PLAYER_SPEED);
                enemyGrp.updateCameraLeft(PLAYER_SPEED);
            }
            else
            {
                player.addXPosition(PLAYER_SPEED);
            }

            //rect.updateCameraLeft(PLAYER_SPEED);
        }
        else if (window.leftArrow)
        {
            if(cam.active && !blockedRight)
            {
                rect.updateCameraRight(PLAYER_SPEED);   
                enemyGrp.updateCameraRight(PLAYER_SPEED);
            }
            else 
            {
                player.subXPosition(PLAYER_SPEED);
            }

        //player.subXPosition(PLAYER_SPEED);
            //rect.updateCameraRight(PLAYER_SPEED);
        }
```

So if the player greater than 400 - "The player Size" then activate camera. If camera active the player dosnt move. Every gameobject like rects or enemygrp moved to new Position.

By displacement of all other elements generated a move illusion.

Maybe bether way to do this or is this the way to go for 2d games?

Thanks for any answer!

Render function:

```
void Window::update(SDL_Rect* rects, int rectsSize, SDL_RectsConfig* config, SDL_Rect* pPositon, SDL_Rect* destPositon, SDL_Rect* weapons, int weaponSize, SDL_Rect* destWeapons, int destSize, SDL_Rect* enemys, SDL_Rect* destEnemys, int enemysSize)
        {
            SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, texture);
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 0x00);

            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, background, NULL, NULL);

            for (int i = 0; i < rectsSize; i++)
            {
                if (config[i].r != NULL && config[i].g != NULL && config[i].b != NULL)
                {
                    SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &rects[i]);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, config[i].r, config[i].g, config[i].b, config[i].a);
                    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rects[i]);
                }
                if (config[i].image != NULL && config[i].font == NULL)
                {
                    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, config[i].image, NULL, &rects[i]);
                }
                else if (config[i].image == NULL && config[i].font != NULL)
                {
                    s << config[i].text;
                    surfaceMessage = TTF_RenderText_Solid(config[i].font, s.str().c_str(), {0, 0, 0}); // as TTF_RenderText_Solid could only be used on SDL_Surface then you have to create the surface first
                    if (surfaceMessage == NULL)
                    {
                        printf("Unable to render text surface! SDL_ttf Error: %s\n", TTF_GetError());
                    }
                    Message = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surfaceMessage);

                    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, Message, NULL, &rects[i]);
                    SDL_FreeSurface(surfaceMessage);
                    SDL_DestroyTexture(Message);
                    s.str("");
                    s.clear();
                }
            }

            /*SDL_RenderDrawRects(renderer, rects, rectsSize);
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
            SDL_RenderFillRects(renderer, rects, rectsSize);*/

            //example render in picture in rects (this is clickeble)
            if (weaponSize == destSize) {
                for (int i = 0; i < weaponSize; i++)
                {
                    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, weaponSheet, &destWeapons[i], &weapons[i]);
                }
            }else
            {
                std::cout << "Error: the sizes from weaponSize and desSize need to be the same." << std::endl;
            }

            //SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, imgs, NULL, &rects[0]);
            if (leftArrow || lastPressed == "SDLK_LEFT") {
                SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer, playerSheet, destPositon, pPositon, NULL, NULL, SDL_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);
                SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, pPositon);
            }
            else {
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, playerSheet, destPositon, pPositon);
                SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, pPositon);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < enemysSize; i++)
            {
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, enemySheet, &destEnemys[i], &enemys[i]);
            }
            //Render value

            //Render Background
            //SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, background, {}, &enemys[i]);

            SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);

            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        }
```

Comment: Panning cameras are usually done the other way around : objects keep their real world-space positions, and only when displaying the offset from the camera is applied visually.

Comment: hey, yeah that make more sense. Now my Question is how i handle this? Have trouble with rendering only the cam position. U have any Idea in SDL? If you can help i can give you more code then u see maybe wath i mean :P

Comment: IIRC SDL's drawing functions aren't designed to integrate a camera : they work in screen space only. What you can do is wrap them inside your own display functions, which will each call the original SDL function while offsetting the coordinates from a global camera position.

Comment: hmm, damn i dont know how i can do that :/ Is the other way all objects move fold? Or maybe give that trouble with performence? Its my first SDL game :P

Comment: There are at least two issues with the approach you have currently : it does not scale well (you have to add calls to update every single object's screen position), and/or information about the camera will leak all through the program and create a mess e.g. in the physics parts of the game.

Comment: What I suggest would be along the lines of `void drawPoint(int x, int y) { SDL_RenderDrawPoint(x + gCam.x, y + gCam.y); }`, where `gCam` would be a global variable of some vector type. If every object uses this function instead of directly calling into SDL, you can then offset everything by changing `gCam`, effectively panning the camera.

Comment: true story @ physics. Thank you for your help. i try some stuff :)

Comment: that with gCam looks nice, if im understand that correctly i must add the cam every object on my render function right? I have added my render function on top. Thank you much

Answer (score 0):

I have found this:

```
SDL_RenderSetViewport(renderer, &cam);
```

i think with that can i do camera :) Without moving all objects.

Comment: That is for drawing *to* a part of the screen, not *from* a part of the world.

Comment: damn yeah, now i see it :(